# Reset Scratch Org

Tags: scratch-org

My company has provided me a scratch org for 30 days.

I made many changes in it but now I don't want those changes. I can manually try deleting it but it will take lots of time. I don't even remember all the changes I made.

So, Is there any sfdx command or any way through which i could reset my scratch org without contacting my admin?

Answer (score 5):

The whole deal of sfdx is that you don't reset scratch orgs - you delete them and create new one. Initially we had our admin use a script to distribute new scratch orgs on request / weekly over slack. Now Salesforce lets add up to 5 people to dev hub so we can do it ourselves.

With scratch orgs you don't need to remember what changes did you made. Just create a new branch in git (`git checkout -b temp_org`) and pull your changes from scratch org (`sfdx force:source:pull`). Switch authorise a new org and push the source there (`sfdx force:source:push -u new@org.username`).

Of course it's easier said than done - you do need to setup your sfdx package first!